# How to create a CSS scope by JavaScript to prevent the CSS effect to another part of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, scope

For example:

I have a page and the code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .wrap a {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have a common JavaScript component which will load a CSS file include the code below:

```
.wrap .link { color: blue; }
```

Then the link will change from `red` to `blue`.

Use iframe can fix this but cause another problem same like display two scrollbar or the lightbox overlay just in part of the page.

I can not change the CSS but I can write a JS loader so do you have some idea to fix this?

Comment: what is your actual requirement. your dynamic css is loading fine and you can restrict it using the class name so no other part will affect the property. why you need iframe here?

Comment: Actual I can not change the markup or style in the page and the CSS file I loaded. I want to figure out a common solution face with this and let the CSS only apply in part of the page like iframe and without the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a selector matches then a rule will apply until overridden by a rule (which sets the same property) further down the cascade.

You can either change your selectors to stop them matching the elements you don't want them to match, or you can override all your rules in that section.

Therefore, you'll have to adapt your markup and styles. You can precede every selector with `#wrapper`. For example, if a rule says `a{color:red}`, substitute that with `#wrapper a {color:red;}`.

HTML5 allows [scoped stylesheets](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp), but only Firefox supports it so far. However there is a you may try a jQuery solution: https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to figure a common solution because there are so many uncontrollable markup or style code.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```js
function changeColor(){
  jQuery(".link").css('color','blue');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .wrap a {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap"><a href="#" class="link" onclick='changeColor()'>link</a></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want to change the link color but when I load some CSS file the CSS maybe effect it.

Comment: Then lazy loading in file including can help you.